# Call Salesforce WebService (POST Method)

Tags: java, list, rest, authentication, post

While calling a POST method web service with salesforce, i have successfully authenticated with OAuth, and i am passing the list of 2 objects in REQUEST BODY, and i have used

```
        method.setRequestBody((NameValuePair[]) siList.toArray());
```

and returned an error

[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lorg.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;

([Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lorg.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;)

SI LIST

---

```
SubscriptionsInfo si = new SubscriptionsInfo();
        // get the token from SalesForce
        JSONObject sfToken = this.sftp.getToken(httpClient);
        si.setAssetId(itmInst.getOrigMfrCd() + TmaticwsConstants.ID_SEPERATOR + itmInst.getItmInstNum());
        si.setSrc("05");
        List<SubscriptionsInfo> siList = new ArrayList<SubscriptionsInfo>();
        siList.add(si);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class SubscriptionsInfo and NameValuePair don't have any parent/child relation and hence you get class cast exception. You could create List of NamedValuePair instead of subscriptionInfo like:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));
```

And then you could create Array like

```
method.setRequestBody(params.toArray());
```

Comment: I did the same as you said, and it keeps asking me to cast parms.toArray() to NameValuePair[]

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", ; expected
 - The method setRequestBody(NameValuePair[]) in the type PostMethod is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Object[])